# Firestore Security Rules: Allow users to create a document only

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have an app with the following characteristics:

- Everyone can read the data (public)
- Admins (authenticated users) have full access (read, write)
- Users can create invoices
- Invoices data is not public

These are the security rules I came up with:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /invoices/{id} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null; // only admins can read data
      allow write: if request.auth != null; // only admins can write data (full access)

      allow create; // users can order stuff, hence they can create
    }
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read; // everything else except the invoices is public
      allow write: if request.auth != null; // if you are an admin, you have full access
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that when creating an invoice with `this.ref = db.collection('invoices').doc()` and getting its id in the db with `this.ref.id`, I get a `Missing or insufficient permissions.` error.

I am clearly doing something wrong here, would appreciate any advise on this.

Comment: In your security rules you specified, that a user can create invoices but is not allowed to read them. So when you write as a user and try to read the created record, you will get that error.

Comment: I removed `db.collection('invoices').doc().id` completely and switched to using `.add` instead of `.set` with the ref, still getting the same error.